# How to query list of Id's in Database using dplyr in r

Tags: mysql, dplyr, tidyverse, dbplyr

I'm new to using r to manipulate data from the database

I want to know how to query a list of Id's in a database table

I want a situation whereby the query returns all records of Id's if found

Before I used to query just one id with the code below

```
start_1<-tbl(connect, "accountbits")%>%
    filter(Tranx_id == "2022011813250866101336997")%>%
                        collect()
```

So it shows the query with details attached with the id.

I want to have many id's like the example below

```
start_2<-tbl(connect, "accountbits")%>%
        filter(Tranx_id = c("2022011813250866101336997","20220115675250866101336997"
         "202201181325086610143246997","2022015433250866101336997")%>%
                            collect()
```

I want it to bring all records attached to this id in the database

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The R operator you are looking for is `%in%`. This checks set intersection:

```r
c(1,3,5) %in% c(1,2,3,4)
# = (TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)
```

because 1 and 3 are in `c(1,2,3,4)`.

You can type `` ?`%in%` ``  at the console for help info about this operator (`` ` `` is the backtick, located next to the number 1 in the top left corner of more keyboards).

There are dbplyr translations defined for `%in%` so a command like:

```r
start_2 <- tbl(connect, "accountbits")%>%
  filter(Tranx_id %in% c("1234","2345","3456"))
```

will translate into SQL like:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM accountbits
WHERE Tranx_id IN (1234, 2345, 3456)
```

and `collect()` will pull those values into local R memory as expected.